# Eclipse e4 disable maximizing part

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

My Eclipse e4 application contains a menu part. This part cannot be moved or closed. Now I'm searching a way to disable maximization of that part stack. So this means disabling the double click on the part tab and removing the maximize button on the part stack. Minimizing should always be possible on the part stack.

Is there some tag available for the part stack or can I do this in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the visibility of the maximize button on the part stack in the CSS for the part stack using `swt-maximize-visible`:

```css
.MPartStack
{
  swt-maximize-visible: false;
}
```

There is also a `swt-minimize-visible`.

If I read the code correctly the MinMaxAddon will then ignore the maximize double click as well.

Comment: How can I do this on one PartStack? I tried using the PartStack ID (#client.partstack.menu{  swt-maximize-visible: false;
}) but without any success.

Comment: The part stack id should work - make sure it is the 'Part Stack' (an id ending in 'menu' doesn't sound like a good part stack id to me).

Comment: Indeed the id did have invalide characters for the css. I changed it to a better one without dots and it's working now.

Comment: '-' characters in the CSS file will match dots in the e4xmi id.